# С помощью регулярных выражений вывести стих, с наибольшим кол-вом "!" знаков

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Не пойму как в данном случае вывести максимальное количество знаков? У меня просто все выводит. По заданию дано 2 стихотворения, с помощью регулярных выражений вывести стих, с наибольшим кол-вом "!" знаков. В моем случае должно получиться число 7.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String textPoems1 = "Часов однообразный бой," +
                " Томительная ночи повесть!!!" +
                " Язык для всех равно чужой" +
                " И внятный каждому, как совесть!";

        String textPoems2 = "Ура! мы ломим; гнутся шведы." +
                " О славный час! о славный вид!" +
                " Еще напор - и враг бежит." +
                " И следом конница" +
                " Пустилась." +
                " Убийством тупятся мечи," +
                " И падшими вся степь" +
                " Покрылась." +
                " Как роем черной саранчи.";

        String textPoems3 = "Ура! мы ломим; гнутся шведы!" +
                " О славный час! о славный вид!" +
                " Еще напор - и враг бежит." +
                " И следом конница" +
                " Пустилась!" +
                " Убийством тупятся мечи," +
                " И падшими вся степь" +
                " Покрылась!!" +
                " Как роем черной саранчи!";

        String poem = textPoems1 + " **************** " + textPoems2 + "********" + textPoems3+"****"+textPoems1;



        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\*]+");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("!+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(poem);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            int i = 0;


            System.out.println(matcher.group());
            Matcher m = p.matcher(matcher.group());

            while (m.find()) {
                i++;
            }


            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит "максимальное количество знаков"?

Comment: макс. кол-во "!" знаков, тут еще важно, что 3 (!!!) идущих подряд, считаю как 1

Comment: Пожалуйста, распишите подробнее все условия прямо в вопросе. Укажите, какое значение должно получиться и почему.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Делаете поиск в стихотворении по `!+`, то есть будет происходиться захват одного и более восклицательных знаков, если подряд идут 1 более, то вхождение будет считаться за один. Далее считаете количество вхождений, и выводите нужный стих :) upd: если вы хотите, то можете захват делать от 1 до 3 знаков включительно, считая за 1 вхождение `!{1,3}`

Comment: А не проще было просто посчитать количество `!`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/

Comment: @gil9red, если я правильно понял, то должно считать знаки !!! как один, но это не точно :D / выше написал вариант.

Comment: Так выводится же 7 в третьем стихе: https://ideone.com/hRCcz8 Что происходит не так?

Comment: @Let's say Pie, ну так все и посчитано, проблема как раз в выводе нужного стиха... С наибольшим кол-вом "!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, регулярные выражения у Вас работают нормально, Вам просто нужно отловить максимум. Для этого нужно отслеживать максимальное количество найденных восклицательных знаков и стих, в котором оно было зафиксировано:

```
//объявим переменные
int maxCount = -1; //заведомо низкое значение
String maxPoem = null;

String poem = ...
...
//в цикле ищем максимум
while (matcher.find()) {
    ...
    //вместо распечатывания текущего значения обновляем максимум
    if(i > maxCount) {
        maxCount = i;
        maxPoem = matcher.group();
    }
}
//после цикла выводим найденный стих и максимальное значение
System.out.println(maxPoem);
System.out.println(maxCount);
```

Обработку `!!!` можно добавить отслеживая длину найденной последовательности восклицательных знаков (`m.group().length()`).

P.S. Советую сразу давать переменным говорящие названия: вместо `i` — `count` или `countExlamationMark`, вместо `matcher` — `poemMatcher` и т.д.

Comment: @William Если Вы хотите внутри цикла распечатывать количество для каждого стиха, то нужно выводить `i`, а не `maxCount`, который выводится только в конце.

Comment: @William Как-то так: https://ideone.com/pK9s6q